# MySQL clubbing two rows as a single one

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `connections` for a friendship system. The columns are:

`id`, `from`,`to`,`direction`,`liking`

Whenever a user sends a friend request, a row is added and direction is set to 1 (1 for forward, 2 for reverse). When the other user accepts the friend request, another row is added and the direction is set to 2.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get a user's friends. But when I do the following query, rows are repeated.

```
            SELECT
                `users`.`name`,`users`.`id`
            FROM
                `connections`,
                `users`
            WHERE
                (
                    `connections`.`from` = 1234 AND
                    `connections`.`to` = `users`.`id` AND
                    `connections`.`direction` = 1
                )
                OR
                (
                    `connections`.`to` = 1234 AND
                    `connections`.`from` = `users`.`id` AND
                    `connections`.`direction` = 2
                )
```

How can this query be modified to include so that rows don't repeat?

**Update**: I'm adding two rows because there's a column `liking`. This value is different for "distinct user connections".

Example -`A` can have a liking of 0.95 for `B`. And `B` can have a liking of just `0.25` for `A`.

Comment: you want requests or accepted friends? or both?and btw why to add another row? why can't you set a status like request=pending, when the other accepts update that too accepted

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you can add an outer query:

```
 SELECT
            name, DISTINCT(id) AS id
 FROM
     (original query)
```

You say that you add a row when the friend accepts the request. That creates two rows. Would it not make more sense to **update** the existing row with the new direction? - ignore this last part as per comment

Comment: There's a column `liking`. This depends upon the user interaction. So I have to add two rows.